# MySQL Get Downline of Member

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a problem when make query to get all downline of the member. This is my table screenshot:

[image]

In this case, M1508004, M1508005 and M1508006 is downline of M1508003. M1508007 is downline of M1508006. Because M1508006, So M1508007 is also downline of M1508003.

Yes, i got a problem when display all downline of M1508003. I have try :

```
SELECT * FROM tb_rekrut WHERE perekrut='M1508003'
```

But it doesnt work. Because it only display M1508004, M1508005 and M1508006.

I also try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_rekrut c1 LEFT JOIN tb_rekrut c2 ON (c2.perekrut = c1.kode_member) WHERE c2.perekrut='M1508003'
```

But, it also doesnt work for me

If you have same problem, let share. Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_rekrut WHERE kode_member>'M1508003'
order by kode_member asc
```

Try that? Maybe it'll work to display every kode_member greater than 'M1580003'